# Stunnel syntax on CentOS?

Tags: centos, centos6, stunnel

I am trying to correct the following stunnel syntax for CentOS 6.x:

```
stunnel -c -f -d 1143 -r imap.foo.tld:993 -P ''
```

The proposed syntax of is not working:

> -c: No such file or directory (2)

To take care of XY problem concerns: I need to migrate my IMAP email from Host A to Host B. Generally I use imapcopy and port 143. However this time host A only supports SSL 993, which imapcopy does not. Stunnel is supposed to get around this, at least according to this tutorial: http://manurevah.com/blah/en/p/Migrate-emails-with-Imapcopy

Answer (score 0):

That page contains a note (unfortunately not very well called out) that is of relevance.

> NOTE: Stunnel doesn't work the same way since Debian Jessie (not sure since which version of stunnel). I've not dug in to it and hence do not know what the new syntax should be (if you know, let me know).

I don't know how you found that page but it is clearly old and out of date. (I can only find one other page that references `stunnel` having command line arguments like that and it lists itself as old more explicitly. Everything else I can find is about the new config file based configuration.)

Comment: Basically I googled on imapcopy with ssl and that guide came up.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [pymap-copy](https://github.com/Schluggi/pymap-copy) instead imapcopy. It's more state of the art and you don't need stunnel.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can write:

```
   stunnel3 -c -f -d 1143 -r imap.foo.tld:993 -P ''
```

stunnel3 is a wrapper script for backward compability